# KiCad Bus on multiple sheets - Are labels the right way to go?

Tags: ethernet, bus, kicad

I want to connect bus-lines via several-sheets in KiCAD 5.0 But I don't know whether I got that right. Please consider the following design:
[image: connecting the bus]

[image: connecting the sheets]

Shown in Figure 1 you can see my connection from the chips output to the signal-bus. I added hierarchical labels to each bus. Those were added with the following function:
[image: Label-function]

Figure 2 shows the parent-sheet in which the network-logic- and the plug-sheet live. There I then added the hierarchical pin with the following function:
[image: Pin-function]

I added the label and the bus on the plug side the same way, as shown in picture below.
[image: Plug-sheet]

**Question:**

1. Is my bus now connected correctly, or am I using the idea of labels wrong?
2. Do labels work with busses the same way the do with single wires?
3. Is it correct, that every line from a bus that has the same name,
   will be connected in the net-list?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, as I'm a bit of a newbie with kicad myself, but my understanding is that the labels attached to wires that enter/exit bus *must* have the bus name as a prefix, and a numeric suffix, so in your example the wires would have to be called `Eth11` and `Eth12`.  Which isn't exactly helpful for understanding the circuit, but seems to be what kicad expects...

Comment: do you have a resource for that?

Comment: I don't know if Kicad has the facility but in OrCad, if I select a net (say LED1) I can highlight the whole net with a drop down menu specific command. If you can do this then you can prove there is connectivity. Alternatively, do a netlist and see if it connects the net to all the parts in the ascii file it creates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is my bus now connected correctly, or am I using the idea of labels
>    wrong?

Local labels (in your example, these are LED1, LED2) will all be connected.  So in your first image, the pin for `LED1_0` and `LED2_0` will be connected.  This is probably not what you want.  You should prefix each wire in a bus with the same string.  So `ETH1_LED1` and `ETH1_LED2` for bus `ETH1` and `ETH2_LED1` and `ETH2_LED2` for bus `ETH2`.

> 2. Do labels work with busses the same way the do with single wires?

No.  There are some bus-specific label requirements (see https://docs.kicad.org/5.1/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#connections-buses)

> 3. Is it correct, that every line from a bus that has the same name, will be connected in the net-list?

Wires connected to buses need to have a local label attached to them identifying which bus member they are connecting.  Each bus member needs to have the same alpha-numeric prefix (e.g. `ETH1_LED`) and a numeric suffix.

Answer (score 5):

Beginning with KiCad 6.0 it's possible to solve this in a multisheet friendly way.

Busses may have names and those names may be aliased to each other. To access a net in one bus it's done by writing `BUSNAME.NETNAME`. To satissfy the ERC check however the hierarchy pin needs to be defined as a bus containing the correct nets, eg `SPI{CLOCK MISO MOSI}`. Thankfully this can be shortened by Bus Definitions for large busses found under Tools to `SPI{SPI_def}`.

One Example:

[image]
[image]

P1:[image] P2: [image]

All pictures were taken with the same net selected. The resistors are there to show which peripheral is currently open.

Comment: Can you depict the bus creation inside the MCU as well, to demonstrate the labelling when nesting buses inside buses? (I am still a bit confused at that step, as `SPI1{SPI}` does not appear as `SPI1{SPI{CLOCK MISO MOSI}}`.)

Comment: You create the Bus Alias in the Schematic Setup Panel. SPI just gets replaced with CLOCK MISO MOSI. So without the alias it would be SPI1{CLOCK MISO MOSI}. But it's best to label things properly especially for big busses live ethernet or a pciex16 bus.

Comment: Thanks for the above. Can you additionally add a newline between the blocks image and the SPI1 breakout image? They appear to be one consolidated schematic.