# Hierarchal Sheet - Bus - Abbreviate Contents

Tags: kicad, bus

In an unrelated [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/603787/101962), user @Steven demonstrated that it is possible to abbreviate the bus contents of a pin label of a hierarchal sheet block.

[image]
[image]

How is this accomplished, such that:

• `SPI1{SPI{CLOCK MISO MOSI}}`
• `SPI2{SPI{CLOCK MISO MOSI}}`

appears solely as:

• `SPI1{SPI}`
• `SPI2{SPI}` ?

Is there a means to display only:

• `SPI1`
• `SPI2`